# Linking with libmaxminddb

Tags: linker, cmake, undefined-reference, geoip

I'm trying to replace libgeoip by libmaxminddb. I'm using CMake build system.
It fails with undefined reference when linking, but -lmaxminddb is present.

liblua_modules.a is the library containing the call to MMDB_open().

```
Linking CXX executable sauer_server
cd /home/piernov/suckerserv/trunk/suckerserv-v5/release_build/src && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/sauer_server.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/sauer_server.dir/engine/server.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sauer_server.dir/fpsgame/server.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sauer_server.dir/hopmod/netbans.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sauer_server.dir/hopmod/startup.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sauer_server.dir/hopmod/scheduler.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sauer_server.dir/hopmod/lua.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sauer_server.dir/hopmod/core_bindings.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sauer_server.dir/hopmod/events.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sauer_server.dir/hopmod/signals.cpp.o  -o sauer_server -rdynamic -lrt -lz libsauertools.so liblua_modules.a -lboost_thread -lenet libsauertools.so -lrt -lz -llua -lmaxminddb fungu/src/net/http/libfungu_http.a -pthread fungu/src/libfungu_string.a -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -lenet -Wl,-rpath,/home/piernov/suckerserv/trunk/suckerserv-v5/release_build/src: 
liblua_modules.a(geoip.cpp.o): In function `load_geoip_database(lua_State*)':
geoip.cpp:(.text+0x13e): undefined reference to `MMDB_open(char const*, unsigned int, MMDB_s*)'
geoip.cpp:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `MMDB_strerror(int)'
```

Comment: Pro tip: put `LANG=EN` in front of any make/compiler/linker to generate english error messages (as a German, I do so myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:
`#include <maxminddb.h>` has to be inside `extern "C"{}` when working with C++.

Comment: Not needed anymore since 1.0.3. `extern "C"{}` is now included in the `maxminddb.h` header.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered altering the linking order? This can often help with your kind of problem.

Instead of

```
target_link_libraries(foo maxminddb object1 object2 object3)
```

move maxminddb further back so that the linker already knows what functions to look for
    target_link_libraries(foo object1 object2 object3 maxminddb)

**note**: If `libmaxminddb` itself needs other libraries, say `liba` and `libb` make sure to still place them behind `maxminddb`

```
target_link_libraries(foo object1 object2 object3 maxminddb liba libb)
```

Comment: Tried to put it at the beginning and at the end, but nothing changed. Tried to add it also directly to the executable's link line (instead of the library's), but it's the same. Strange it works without problem when I switch back to linking with libGeoIp (along with reverting the code change for libmaxminddb) or when I compile the libmaxminddb's sample program.